# interpretation of coefficients from cph with restricted cubic spline transformed independent variable(s)

Tags: regression

I have used restricted cubic spline transformed to fix a Cox PH model using Dr. Frank Harrell's cph() from the rms package. The overall chi-square p-value is not significant, but I wonder how to interpret the two coefficients.

The following is the output

Cox Proportional Hazards Model

cph(formula = surv ~ rcs(N.mut.nonsynon, 3), data = si, x = TRUE, 
     y = TRUE, surv = TRUE)

```
                    Model Tests    Discrimination    
                                          Indexes
```

Obs        26    LR chi2      4.20    R2       0.155
 Events     15    d.f.            2    Dxy      0.302
 Center 1.0883    Pr(> chi2) 0.1226    g        0.700
                  Score chi2   3.73    gr       2.014
                  Pr(> chi2) 0.1550

```
             Coef    S.E.   Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
```

N.mut.nonsynon   0.0420 0.0237  1.77  0.0762
 N.mut.nonsynon' -0.0294 0.0162 -1.82  0.0691

Specifically, did the model fit two terms, N.mut.nonsynon and N.mut.nonsynon'? How should I call these two terms? How do I describe the relationship between N.mut.nonsynon and the relative HR? In this case, the two coefficients have opposite signs - of course the Wald tests are not significant, but what if they are significant AND have opposite signs? Should I describe the result in 'segments' in the predictor-log Relative plot like this one?[image]

Thanks! -Wenbin